# Expectation number of cycles in a Erdős–Rényi random directed graph $G(n,p)$

Tags: probability, graph-theory, expectation, random, random-graphs

Let $G \sim G(n,p)$ be a directed [Erdős–Rényi random graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) 
with $n$ vertices and the probability $p$ that 
there is a directed edge between any two ordered pairs of vertices.

What is the expected number of cycles in $G$?
Is there an exact formula or an upper bound and lower bound
on the expected number of simple cycles in $G$?

Comment: Hi @Anders. Welcome! You might like to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Answer (score 12):

Let $X$ be the total number of cycles, 
$X_k$ the number of cycles of length $k$ in $G$, and
$Y_k$ the number of cycles of length $k$ in a random graph of size $k$.

Note that:

- ${\sf E}[X] = \sum_{k=2}^n {\sf E}[X_k]$.
- ${\sf E}[X_k] = {n \choose k} {\sf E}[Y_k]$.
- ${\sf E}[Y_k] = (k!/k)p^k = (k-1)!p^k$.

The last one is because a cycle of length $k$ 
is a permutation of numbers from $1$ to $k$ 
but the first vertex does not matter (a cycle does not have a first vertex).
The probability of each edge being present is $p$,
so the probability of $k$ edges being present is $p^k$.

We have:

\begin{align*}
{\sf E}[X] &= \sum_{k=2}^n E[X_k] \\ 
&= \sum_{k=2}^n {n \choose k} E[Y_k] \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^n {n \choose k} (k-1)! p^k \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} (k-1)! p^k \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k} p^k \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{n\ldots (n-k+1)}{k} p^k \\
\end{align*}

For a simple lower bound 
we can drop the first half of the sum:
\begin{align*}
&\geq \sum_{k=n/2}^{n} \frac{n\ldots (n-k+1)}{k} p^k \\
&\geq \sum_{k=n/2}^{n} \frac{(n/2)^{k}}{n} p^k \\
&\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n/2}^{n} (np/2)^{k} \\
&= \frac{(\frac{np}{2})^{n+1}-(\frac{np}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\frac{np}{2}-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: What is n?  DId you mean to say a random graph of n nodes?

Comment: $n$ is the number of vertices. The OP defines the model.

Comment: I should have said a bit more:  What does "in a random graph of size k" mean - did you mean "of n nodes"?

Comment: By symmetry, I reduce the question of the expected number of cycles in $D(n,p)$ to the expected number of cycles in $D(k,p)$ (we are looking at directed graphs here, so I use $D(n,p)$ instead of $G(n,p)$), In particular, $$ E[\# \text{ of cycles in }D(n,p) \text{ of length }k] = {n \choose k}E[\# \text{ of cycles in }D(k,p)\text{ of length }k]$$

Comment: Should k start from 3?